# How can I transfer system data to a new 3DS without using System Transfer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I recently punched my 3DS while playing Mario Kart and cracked the screen. I've bought a new 3DS console, but can't do a System Transfer because the broken 3DS can't connect to the internet.

Is there any way I can use the old SD card with all of my saved data in my new 3DS? I tried to transfer the data, from the old card to the new card, but the data will not appear in the new console. I don't want to lose my Ambassador Certificate and NES & Gameboy games!

Comment: Try contacting Nintendo's support.